# Calculating Slopes in Numpy (or Scipy)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to find the fastest and most efficient way to calculate slopes using Numpy and Scipy. I have a data set of three Y variables and one X variable and I need to calculate their individual slopes. For example, I can easily do this one row at a time, as shown below, but I was hoping there was a more efficient way of doing this. I also don't think linregress is the best way to go because I don't need any of the auxiliary variables like intercept, standard error, etc in my results. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    import numpy as np
    from scipy import stats

    Y = [[  2.62710000e+11   3.14454000e+11   3.63609000e+11   4.03196000e+11
        4.21725000e+11   2.86698000e+11   3.32909000e+11   4.01480000e+11
        4.21215000e+11   4.81202000e+11]
        [  3.11612352e+03   3.65968334e+03   4.15442691e+03   4.52470938e+03
        4.65011423e+03   3.10707392e+03   3.54692896e+03   4.20656404e+03
        4.34233412e+03   4.88462501e+03]
        [  2.21536396e+01   2.59098311e+01   2.97401268e+01   3.04784552e+01
        3.13667639e+01   2.76377113e+01   3.27846013e+01   3.73223417e+01
        3.51249997e+01   4.42563658e+01]]
    X = [ 1990.  1991.  1992.  1993.  1994.  1995.  1996.  1997.  1998.  1999.] 
    slope_0, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(X, Y[0,:])
    slope_1, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(X, Y[1,:])
    slope_2, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(X, Y[2,:])
    slope_0 = slope/Y[0,:][0]
    slope_1 = slope/Y[1,:][0]
    slope_2 = slope/Y[2,:][0]
    b, a = polyfit(X, Y[1,:], 1)
    slope_1_a = b/Y[1,:][0]
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The linear regression calculation is, in one dimension, a [vector calculation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression).  This means we can combine the multiplications on the entire **Y** matrix, and then vectorize the fits using the *axis* parameter in numpy.  In your case that works out to the following

```
((X*Y).mean(axis=1) - X.mean()*Y.mean(axis=1)) / ((X**2).mean() - (X.mean())**2)
```

You're not interested in fit quality parameters but most of them can be obtained in a similar manner.

Answer (score 70):

The fastest and the most efficient way would be to use a native scipy function from [linregress](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html) which calculates everything:

> slope : slope of the regression line
>
> intercept : intercept of the regression line
>
> r-value : correlation coefficient
>
> p-value : two-sided p-value for a hypothesis test whose null hypothesis is that the slope is zero
>
> stderr : Standard error of the estimate

And here is an example:

```
a = [15, 12, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 6, 5, 3]
b = [10, 25, 17, 11, 13, 17, 20, 13, 9, 15]
from scipy.stats import linregress
linregress(a, b)
```

will return you:

```
LinregressResult(slope=0.20833333333333337, intercept=13.375, rvalue=0.14499815458068521, pvalue=0.68940144811669501, stderr=0.50261704627083648)
```

P.S. Just a mathematical formula for slope:

[image]

Answer (score 18):

This clear one-liner should be efficient enough without scipy:

```
slope = np.polyfit(X,Y,1)[0]
```

Finally you should get

```
import numpy as np

Y = np.array([
    [  2.62710000e+11, 3.14454000e+11, 3.63609000e+11, 4.03196000e+11, 4.21725000e+11, 2.86698000e+11, 3.32909000e+11, 4.01480000e+11, 4.21215000e+11, 4.81202000e+11],
    [  3.11612352e+03, 3.65968334e+03, 4.15442691e+03, 4.52470938e+03, 4.65011423e+03, 3.10707392e+03, 3.54692896e+03, 4.20656404e+03, 4.34233412e+03, 4.88462501e+03],
    [  2.21536396e+01, 2.59098311e+01, 2.97401268e+01, 3.04784552e+01, 3.13667639e+01, 2.76377113e+01, 3.27846013e+01, 3.73223417e+01, 3.51249997e+01, 4.42563658e+01]]).T
X = [ 1990,  1991,  1992,  1993,  1994,  1995,  1996,  1997,  1998,  1999] 

print np.polyfit(X,Y,1)[0]
```

Output is [1.54983152e+10 9.98749876e+01 1.84564349e+00]

Answer (score 10):

A representation that's simpler than the accepted answer:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 11)
y = np.linspace(0, 20, 11)
y = np.c_[y, y,y]

X = x - x.mean()
Y = y - y.mean()

slope = (X.dot(Y)) / (X.dot(X))
```

The equation for the slope comes from [Vector notation for the slope of a line using simple regression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2565098/vector-notation-for-the-slope-of-a-line-using-simple-regression/2642719#2642719).

Comment: I don't think this is correct! This only works because you broadcasted the same values to y three times. The problem is that the mean is calculated over all axes by default not just one. So you are subtracting the mean over all different y sets instead of the mean for each y set.

Answer (score 9):

The way I did it is using the `np.diff()` function:

```py
dx = np.diff(xvals)
dy = np.diff(yvals)
slopes = dy / dx
```

Comment: Do you expect that dx is non-zero?

Answer (score 7):

As said before, you can use scipy's linregress. Here is how to get just the slope out:

```py
from scipy.stats import linregress
        
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [2, 3, 8, 9, 22]

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = linregress(x, y)
print(slope)
```

Keep in mind that doing it this way, since you are computing extra values like `r_value` and `p_value`, will take longer than calculating only the slope manually. However, Linregress is pretty quick.

Source: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html

Answer (score 2):

With X and Y defined the same way as in your question, you can use:

```
dY = (numpy.roll(Y, -1, axis=1) - Y)[:,:-1]
dX = (numpy.roll(X, -1, axis=0) - X)[:-1]

slopes = dY/dX
```

numpy.roll() helps you align the next observation with the current one, you just need to remove the last column which is the not useful difference between the last and first observations. Then you can calculate all slopes at once, without scipy.

In your example, `dX` is always 1, so you can save more time by computing `slopes = dY`.

Comment: I need to clarify a bit because I am only looking for a single slope for all the points; what you get when you run a linear regression of Y on X. For example, slope, intercept = polyfit(X, Y[1,:], 1) gives me a slope value of 99.87.

Comment: This gives you a slope for each set of data in Y (3).

Answer (score 0):

I built upon the other answers and the original regression formula to build a function which works for any tensor.
It will calculate the slopes of the data along the given axis. So, if you have arbitrary tensors `X[i,j,k,l], Y[i,j,k,l]` and you want to know the slopes for all other axes along the data in the third axis, you can call it with `calcSlopes( X, Y, axis = 2 )`.

```py
import numpy as np

def calcSlopes( x = None, y = None, axis = -1 ):
    assert x is not None or y is not None

    # assume that the given single data argument are equally
    # spaced y-values (like in numpy plot command)
    if y is None:
        y = x
        x = None

    # move axis we wanna calc the slopes of to first
    # as is necessary for subtraction of the means
    # note that the axis 'vanishes' anyways, so we don't need to swap it back
    y = np.swapaxes( y, axis, 0 )
    if x is not None:
        x = np.swapaxes( x, axis, 0 )

    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression
    # beta = sum_i ( X_i - <X> ) ( Y_i - <Y> ) / ( sum_i ( X_i - <X> )^2 )
    if x is None:
        # axis with values to reduce must be trailing for broadcast_to,
        # therefore transpose
        x = np.broadcast_to( np.arange( y.shape[0] ), y.T.shape ).T
        x = x - ( x.shape[0] - 1 ) / 2. # mean of (0,1,...,n-1) is n*(n-1)/2/n
    else:
        x = x - np.mean( x, axis = 0 )
    y = y - np.mean( y, axis = 0 )

    # beta = sum_i x_i y_i / sum_i x_i*^2
    slopes = np.sum( np.multiply( x, y ), axis = 0 ) / np.sum( x**2, axis = 0 )

    return slopes
```

It also has the gimmick to work with only equally spaced y data being given. So for example:

```py
y = np.array( [
    [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ],
    [ 2, 4, 6, 8 ]
] )

print( calcSlopes( y, axis = 0 ) )
print( calcSlopes( y, axis = 1 ) )

x = np.array( [
    [ 0, 2, 4, 6 ],
    [ 0, 4, 8, 12 ]
] )

print( calcSlopes( x, y, axis = 1 ) )
```

Output:

```
[1. 2. 3. 4.]
[1. 2.]
[0.5 0.5]
```

Comment: As you use numpy.. how better is it than numpy.polyfit ?

Comment: @kimstik What is "better" for you? I did no performance benchmark. I just didn't want to call polyfit in a loop, which I had had to do because to my knowledge polyfit can't handle arbitrary tensors. So, in that regard, using pure numpy is better in that it enables me to do what I want in the first place.

Comment: "better" in terms of "fastest and most efficient way to calculate slopes using Numpy and Scipy". At this point tensors is off-topic. numpy.polyfit is still pure numpy. Your approach is even not required numpy and can be pure python.

Comment: division-by-0 on axis=0 not managed. Matrix slope calculation for your example can be reduced to:
"np.mean(np.diff(y, axis=1) / np.diff(x, axis=1), axis=1)".

By the way.. Do you have test examples of tensors with 4 axis?

Answer (score -1):

Well it depends on the number of points you have. If you have two points, go with `linregress` from `stats` of the `scipy`. If more, go with `theilslope` because it avoids as much as 29% outliers in the data and calculates best slope. The former simply considers all the samples, not worying about the outliers, and calculates best slope that fits all the samples.

```
from scipy import stats

slope1 = stats.linregress([2,4],[1,2])[0] # (ydata,xdata)

slope2 = stats.theilslopes([0.2,0.5,0.9,0.4],[1,2,3,4],0.9) # (ydata,xdata,confidence)
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is example of visual, how to predict the coeffiecent of linear regression.
How to calculate the slope and intercept just for example for newbie. Happy learning.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about "fastest and most efficient way to calculate slopes using Numpy and Scipy" ?