# How I can get the same result in Python what I get by using SLOPE in Excel?

Tags: python

```
a= [-0.10266667,0.02666667,0.016 ,0.06666667,0.08266667]
b= [5.12,26.81,58.82,100.04,148.08]
```

the result in excel SLOPE(a,b)  is 0.001062
How I can get the same result in Python what I get by using SLOPE in Excel?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating Slopes in Numpy (or Scipy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538525/calculating-slopes-in-numpy-or-scipy)

Comment: `slope = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

x = np.array([5.12,26.81,58.82,100.04,148.08]).reshape((-1, 1))
y = np.array([-0.10266667,0.02666667,0.016 ,0.06666667,0.08266667])

model = LinearRegression().fit(x, y)

print(model.coef_)

# methods and attributes available
print(dir(model))
```

In excel, `SLOPE` arguments are in the order y, x. I used those names here so it would be more obvious.

The `reshape` just makes `x` a lists of lists which is what is required. `y` is just needs to be a list. `model` has many other methods and attributes available. See `dir(model)`.